# Creating a method that will set values on a object, return the object or set using the passed param?

Tags: java, methods

I am creating a method in my Java project which simply set values of an object which in turns be called by another method to do some processing. Common approaches are returning the object being set and the other one is setting the object which was passed in the parameter.

Can you give me advantages and disadvantages of both scenario(even its memory consumption or performance or even the minor differences or when to use them), both works but maybe there are key points that I missed.

Return the object being set.

```
public Vehicles setVehiclesDetails(){
    Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
    List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setName("Tesla Model S");
    car.setBrand("Tesla");
    car.setPrice(45000);
    carList.add(car);
    List<Bike> bikeList = new ArrayList<>();
    Bike bike = new Bike();
    bike.setName("A");
    bikeList.add(bike);
    vehicles.setCarList(carList);
    vehicles.setBikeList(bikeList);
    return vehicles;
}
```

Set using the object passed in the parameter

```
public void setCarDetails(Vehicles vehicles){
    List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setName("Tesla Model S");
    car.setBrand("Tesla");
    car.setPrice(45000);
    vehicles.setCarList(carList);
}
```

The calling method

```
public void processVehicles(){
    Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();

    //method1
    vehicles = setVehiclesDetail();
    //other codes to process vehicles

    //method2
    setVehiclesDetail(vehicles);
    //other codes to process vehicles
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a constructor that receives those parameters?

Comment: This is a fairly false comparison: Those methods do very different things and would be designed for different purposes. You can't really directly compare them.

Comment: Do you want the user of your method to provide a `Car`, or do you want to create one for them? That is **literally** the only question, and there is no definitive answer to it. There is no "memory consumption or performance" difference, and you would do well to forget about such micro-optimisations as soon as possible.

Comment: First case honors `immutability`, where in concurrent environment, you are modifying same object, new instance of object will guarantee that, previous process does not get messed up. Of course it will hurt your performance. JVM is clever enough to keep up with small lived objects. Second case honors memory, but in concurrent environment, you will want to do synchronization.

Comment: @muradm - Not really, not if `Car` has those `setXYZ` methods mutating the instance like that. Now, if the first one accepted a `Car` and returns a new car with modifications (not using `setXYZ` methods), that would be a good example of using immutable objects. But the first one isn't really related to immutability, it's just a builder function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, true, somehow I assumed, that he wants to modify the existing object. Otherwise there is no difference or point in treating them as different methods.

Comment: hello updated use case, i guess both can be compare by now. Thanks!

Comment: @djrumix123 - On SO, it's **not** okay to change the question once it has answers so that the answers are invalidated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, we have a misunderstanding about the question, I have updated the use case, so I can point-out what I really ask

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answers [the question originally asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53150948/1), not the significantly-edited version.

---

These methods really do fundamentally different things, it doesn't make a lot of sense to compare them: One *creates* an object, sets some properties, and returns it; the other sets properties on an *existing* object.

Obviously, since your first version creates a new `Car`, and creating an object consumes memory, in that sense the first version consumes more memory than the second. But if code calling your second version had to create the `Car` to pass into it, there's no sigificant memory or performance difference.

It's a bit odd to have a method called "setCarDetails" that doesn't accept a `Car` to set them on. The method that returns a new car would typically have a name reflecting that, like "createCar" or "buildCar" or "buildCarWithDetails". But even more typically, it would simply be a *constructor* (and would accept the details to set, rather than hardcoding them, though of course that varies by use case).